# Play E-Drums with Pedals only?

Tags: equipment, percussion

Let me explain. We are a two-man-group. My mate is doing guitar and vocals and I am doing bass and percussion. Some time ago I build (soldering and then also really assembling) myself a set of 6 drum-pads I play with my feet and we have an old Yamaha drum computer that uses the MIDI from the drum-pads to generate drum samples. So far so good. However the build quality of these drum pads is as lousy as you would expect from someone who is mathematician by training (me) and the drum computer does not use the attack values from the MIDI signal. Hence, the drum sometimes are not triggered but if they are they always sound the same.

However, I had an idea, to buy an electric drum set and indead of connecting the toms and snare and so forth to the main component. **So, I was wondering if it is possible to play an E-drum set only with, say six, pedals?** This way I have all the advantages of E-drums available at my feet.

EDIT: I want to clarify, that I just want to connect another kick pad to the input for the snare. I assume that the drum-computer is fed by wires from all electric components. So I thought, why not connect another kick-drum to the input for the snare. Shouldn't I then be able to hear a snare sound, when I hit the pedal whose respective kick is connected to the snare?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A complete set of pads will only contain one drum pad, playable with a beater, as in a kick drum. The other pads are designed for hitting with sticks. So you could buy six 'bass drum' pads and six pedals, but that gets complex in playability.

Maybe the drum pads could be usable, but then you'd have to mount them and take up a fair bit of space. Then fit pedals.

I'm sure I've seen a one octave pedalboard (I built one for MIDI from an old organ set to play bass pedals) that is programmed to play all 13 notes. That could be re-programmed to make 13 drum sounds - easier to play, set up, break down, and could even be re-programmable with the right 'brain'. Or programmed for the Yamaha module.

It's very simple to plug *any* drum head into *any* input on the module. Whichever input used will produce the sound written on that input. So one drum can be inputted to make any of the sounds you want. But I still prefer my idea..!

Comment: I don't want to hit the other pads with pedals. I edit my question accordingly.

Comment: You have not edited clearly enough for me. It still says play with only 6 pedals, then you say you don't want to hit the other pads with pedals. Unclear. Header says pedals only. Read my edit.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but this could be an interesting alternative.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-nCJxizxvI

Comment: +1 There are definitely midi pedal controllers at different price ranges that would fit this need. Some are more modern with typical button style door pedals, others imitate the organ pedal style.